# How to set timeout for urllib2.OpenDirector open() method

Tags: python, settimeout, urllib2

i'm using some urllib2.HTTPHandler subclasses as a proxy with the [socksipy project](http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/).

Everything works fine with them except when they hit a URL that hangs. Setting the timeout both globally and through the OpenDirector.open() method doesn't do anything.

Here are the urllib2.HTTPHandlers:

```
# get the socksipy project code
import socks

class SocksiPyConnection(httplib.HTTPConnection):
    def __init__(self, proxytype, proxyaddr, proxyport = None, rdns = False, username = None, password = None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.proxyargs = (proxytype, proxyaddr, proxyport, rdns, username, password)
        httplib.HTTPConnection.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def connect(self):
        self.sock = socks.socksocket()
        self.sock.setproxy(*self.proxyargs)
        if isinstance(self.timeout, float):
            self.sock.settimeout(self.timeout)
        self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))

class SocksiPyHandler(urllib2.HTTPHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kw = kwargs
        urllib2.HTTPHandler.__init__(self)

    def http_open(self, req):
        def build(host, port=None, strict=None, timeout=0):
            conn = SocksiPyConnection(*self.args, host=host, port=port, strict=strict, timeout=timeout, **self.kw)
            return conn
        return self.do_open(build, req)
```

I've tried setting the timeout globally as **socket.setdefaulttimeout(30)** without any success. I've also tried setting the timeout when i instantiate **SocksiPyConnection**  above. And finally i've tried to set the timeout using the **OpenDirector.open** method [as the API says it takes a timeout](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.OpenerDirector.open) without success.

Test code that hangs:

```
import sys
# import socksipy base code
sys.path.append( "/parent/path/to/socks.py" )
import socks 
import urllib2
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(30)
proxyhost = "responder.w2"
proxyport = 1050
sys.path.append( "/home/gcorradini" )
from sock_classes import SocksiPyHandler
opener = urllib2.build_opener(SocksiPyHandler(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, proxyhost, int(proxyport)) )
resp = opener.open("http://erma.orr.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/mapserver/charts?version=1.1.1&service=wms&request=GetCapabilities", timeout=30.0)
# i just hang here forever
```

Comment: It says: Changed in version 2.6: timeout was added. Which version are you using?

Comment: I was researching this subject also. I've run into discussion that this timeout controls the connection timeout but not the read/write idle timeout. I found this old post about the issue as I am trying to dig up more information. http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/563167

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the "hanging/timeout" issue i mentioned above was in fact a "blocking" issue in the [sockssipy socks.py](http://sourceforge.net/projects/socksipy/) code. If you are hitting an endpoint that still responds with 200 but sends no data (0 bytes) then socks.py will block cause that's how it's written. Here is the before and after for creating your own timeout:

**socks.py BEFORE**:

```
def __recvall(self, bytes):
    """__recvall(bytes) -> data
    Receive EXACTLY the number of bytes requested from the socket.
    Blocks until the required number of bytes have been received.
    """
    data = ""
    while len(data) < bytes:
       data = data + self.recv(bytes-len(data))
    return data
```

**socks.py AFTER with timeout**:

```
def __recvall(self, bytes):
    """__recvall(bytes) -> data
    Receive EXACTLY the number of bytes requested from the socket.
    Blocks until the required number of bytes have been received.
    """
    data = self.recv(bytes, socket.MSG_WAITALL)
    if type(data) not in (str, unicode) or len(data) != bytes:
        raise socket.timeout('timeout')
    return data
```